# Can you put multiple assignment in rescue modifier?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, modifier

Suppose I have this :

```
item_one = Object.find(1) rescue item_one, value = [Object.first, true]
```

This actually does not work. It returns this :

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end
```

Does anyone know how to syntactically put multiple assignment in rescue modifier?

**Side note:**

Boris recommend setting up rescue statements this way :

```
begin
  i1 = Object.find 1
rescue NoMethodError
  i1, v = Object.first, true 
end
```

Comment: I am a huge fan of making the Ruby lines long, but rescue one-liner is really really only for the very simplest situations.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky What would you recommend alternatively?

Comment: Multiline rescue: `begin i1 = Object.find 1; rescue NoMethodError; i1, v = Object.first, true end`. It removes the syntactic ambiguity and gives you a huge advantage of specifying which error you want to rescue. Trust me, oneliner `rescue` is just a very unhealthy syntactic candy, be sure to use them very sparingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parenthesis. So you are rescuing from the assignment:

```
(item_one = Object.find(1)) rescue item_one, value = [Object.first, true]
```

Comment: Touché, that makes it so `item_one` represents the array for both `item_one` and `value`